# Last elements of an unordered list getting cut on bottom of page [New Issue]

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm building a chat application and a small issue that I've run into is that sometimes the last 1 or 2 messages left in the unordered list will be cut off at the bottom where you are able to see about half of the 2nd to last list item and then the last item is completely underneath the page. I then have to post another message in order to scroll down and see those previous 2 messages being cut off:

Video: http://gyazo.com/2f8e636bfec671240ae76b5eecdd1a17

Looks like the issue here is that the text box at the bottom is actually covering the list item (s).

Comment: You really need to post your code for someone to help you out. At this point it could be anything.

Comment: Ah looks like i found out the issue, the text box at the very bottom is actually hiding the listed items.

Answer (score 0):

Add overflow:scroll property for your ul tag.  please upload your code in fiddle for further help.

Here is the reference of overflow property
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp